# What is the status of US20120305616A1?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20120305616](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120305616)

This patent application publication was filed May 2011 and I can't find any more details on this publication. How do I find out the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

application no-13/149,420 in the name of Charles Scott Smith is Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action on 09-13-2014. kindly check the link below. http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair